# Need Date functionality for Day Week Month Year in Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, angular-material, ionic4

I Would like to show the current day, Week, Month, and Year in Angular If I click on Day need to show the current day so that I can click on greater than symbol to get the next day as well as the previous day when clicking on less than symbol like that I need to display week and month and year.[image]

Comment: Did you try anything? What problem do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
      if (this.tabID === "Day") {
        const nextDay = new Date(myDate1);
        nextDay.setDate(myDate1.getDate() + 1);
        this.currentDate = nextDay;
        console.log("next ", nextDay);
      }
      if (this.tabID === "Month") {
        // for month
        const nextMonth = new Date(myDate1);
        nextMonth.setMonth(myDate1.getMonth() + 1);
        console.log("month ", nextMonth);
        this.currentDate = nextMonth;
      }
      if (this.tabID === "Week") {
        // for next week
        const firstDay = new Date(this.currentDate);
        const nextWeek = new Date(firstDay.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        console.log("next week> ", nextWeek);
        this.currentDate = nextWeek;
        const current = new Date(this.currentDate); // get current date
        const weekstart = current.getDate(); // - 1 - current.getDay() + 1;
        const weekend = weekstart - 6; // end day is the first day + 6
        this.weekStart = new Date(current.setDate(weekstart)); // first day of week is Sunday
        this.weekEnd = new Date(current.setDate(weekend)); // last day of week is Saturday
        console.log("weekStart ", this.weekStart, "WeekEnd ", this.weekEnd);
      }
      if (this.tabID === "Year") {
        const nextMonth = new Date(myDate1);
        nextMonth.setFullYear(myDate1.getUTCFullYear() + 1);
        console.log("month ", nextMonth);
        this.currentDate = nextMonth;
      }
    }```
    by doing this I resolved the issue.
    this code is for only greater than icon in image
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [ion-datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) is what you are looking for.